# Automatically including posts from the last seven days inside a FEEDBLOCK for a MailChimp RSS Campaign

Tags: rss, mailchimp

So, I'm working on trying to improve a Mailchimp RSS campaign that was created by one of my coworkers.

The email that gets sent out is a list of posts from different categories in our website.

So to do this the RSS campaign is made up of different FEEDBLOCKS – one FEEDBLOCK for each kind of category on the website. An example of one of the FEEDBLOCKs looks like this (which is pretty standard and basic, I guess):

```
*|FEEDBLOCK:http://website.com/specific-category/feed|*

*|FEEDITEMS:[$count=2]|*
*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|* 
*|END:FEEDITEMS|*
*|END:FEEDBLOCK|*
```

The thing I want to fix is for the FEEDBLOCK to only show new posts from the past 7 days (the Mailchimp campaign goes out once a week). At the moment, we do this manually by changing the number in the `*|FEEDITEMS:[$count=2]|*` field. We have to manually count the number of new posts on the website each week and input the new count number so the correct number of new posts are displayed on the email.

I'm pretty new to using RSS feeds and Mailchimp but it seems to me from knowing some basic coding that there should be a way to do this automatically, rather than having to manually change the count number for every FEEDBLOCK before we send out the email to our subscribers.

Can any of you give me any advice on how I can change the code we're using to update the count number automatically?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is how Feedblock works - but with the standard RSS merge tags available in Mailchimp, the schedule of the email determines how many items are pulled in. For example, I have an rss feed scheduled for once a week - with no item number parameters the code - Mailchimp pulls in only the articles posted to my feed since the last time the campaign sent - i.e. in one week it can be anywhere from 3 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing. FEEDBLOCKS and FEEDITEMS do not act like RSSFEED and RSSITEMS. If you use FEEDBLOCKS the RSS dates entered in the "RSS Feed" step are not used!

This is what I received from MailChimp: "Any FEEDBLOCK tag in a sense will be its own feed so any dates set for the RSS campaign are ignored. FEEDBLOCK's are usually used for non-rss campaigns to display something from another feed. You can only control how many post are shown when using the FEEDBLOCK tag."

Unfortunately I, like you, have only the manual solution! I am not a coder, but I think the rssfeed itself has to be changed. That would be to build an RSS feed that limits entries to a certain date range i.e., previous 7 days ending with previous full day.